# Task.ContinueWith await all tasks in sequence

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I'm trying to aggregate tasks in a sequence where I can await one task and retrieve the final result, without prematurely awaiting the first task. Something like

```
public Task<int> AddTwo(this Task<int> antecedant)
{
  // This hasn't worked for me, returning the new continuation task.
  return first.ContinueWith(task => task.Result + 2);
}

public Task<int> GetAsyncCount()
{
  // Some async stuff in real code.
  return await Task.FromResult(10);
}

var continuation = GetAsyncCount().AddTwo();

// I want to wait here for original task and then the continuation task.
var countPlus2 = await continuation;

Console.WriteLine(${countPlus2});
```

In my experience this doesn't work and breaks VS debugger, it'll skip the scope I'm in and go to the next line ostensibly in the outer scope, to be honest I'm not completely sure what's happening there. What I'm imagining is happening is I'm waiting for task 2 to finish, but it won't start until task 1 is completed and I never await task 1. What I'm looking for is a way to say "await this task and the chain of tasks it depends on"), and I *really* don't want to make the caller aware of every task in the chain like this

```
public (Task<int> first, Task<int> second) AddTwo(this Task<int> antecedant)
{
  var next = antecedant.ContinueWith(task => task.Result + 2);
  return (antecedant, next);
{
...
var (first, second) = GetATask().AddTwo();

await first;
var resultICareAbout = await second;
```

which seems to be the implied way to do it in the microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks#handle-exceptions-thrown-from-continuations). Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? Since I still want to delay waiting for the execution of task 1 until I need the result of task 2, I can't just do `await antecedant()` when making the continuation. I don't want to execute task 1 when I'm building the sequence of steps, I'd rather the code using my code decide when to wait for it all to run.

Comment: Can you give a clear example of what you want to do? If B depends on A, why not just have B call A?

Comment: What about `public Task<int> AddTwo(this Task<int> antecedant)
{ var result = await first; return result + 2; }` and then just decide when to `await` *that* task?

Comment: You both recommend the same idea in different ways and you're both right, I don't know why that thought didn't cross my mind. Still getting the hang of async programming, the obvious approach is not obvious at all times. If either of you made a response I'd mark it as a solution

Comment: @StephenCleary I think he wants to take the functor (x => x +2) and apply it to the monad `GetAsyncCount`

Comment: @Anthony I don't think the problem is `async`. I think you want to learn about monadic functional programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A task that is awaited won't magically finish until whatever is awaiting it is *also* awaited.

So you can just do

```
public async Task<int> AddTwo(this Task<int> antecedant)
{
    var result = await first;
    return result + 2;
}
```

and then just decide when to await *that* task.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to learn how to compose the monad `Task` using the `map` applicative with the `(int x) => x +2` functor.

```
public async static Task<TRet> Select<T, TRet>(this Task<T> task, Func<T, TRet> selector)
{
    return selector(await task);
} 

var result = await GetAsyncCount().Select(x => x +2);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If on the other hand you want to curry the Selector and the Applicative. You can:

```
Func<Task<int>, Func<int>> asyncAddTwo = task => task.Select(x => x + 2);

var result = await asyncAddTwo(GetAsyncCount());
```

Comment: This is surprisingly similar to my end result, as I was making Task extensions on a wrapper with a functional API (a result wrapper class), and ended up with `return task.Result.Map(nextFunc);`. But I accepted the other answer because it answers the question explicitly asked

Comment: @Anthony You should not be calling `Task.Result`. That API call is blocking, and very often a cause of deadlocks. In general, C# calls `Map` `Select` given the history with Linq2SQL.

Comment: isn't `await task` blocking in the same way that `task.Result` is?

Comment: @Anthony No. `await` is non blocking. With `Task.Result` the thread is parked/sleeped until the `Task` completes. With `await` the thread goes back to the scheduler to pick up more work. A deadlock occurs if the work that is within the `Task` is waiting for this thread in the scheduler. Additionally, you require more `Thread`s when using `Task.Result`. You should read StephenCleary's blog posts on the subject, starting with "There is no thread".

Comment: @Anthony, there are a bunch of subtitle bugs and pitfalls in async you need to avoid, just copy my code. You need to learn about `SynchronizationContext` etc. Otherwise, always use `await` rather than `Task.Result`.